# Why does the sshd command’s behavior vary depending on the network?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I’d like to ssh into Termux using OpenSSH. I have found so far that what is output from `logcat -s ‘sshd:*’` depends on the network I’m connected to from the phone I’m running Termux on. Once, I got “Listening on Port 8022”, and ssh’ing in worked. Other times, I’ve gotten some output, but not that it’s listening on a port, and the ssh didn’t work. When I do sshd and my phone is connected via cellular data, the `logcat` commands returns nothing.

So, why does sshd depend on the network you’re connected to? Do you have to configure your network to allow the sshd connection or something?

This is the output of `logcat` when I'm on my office WiFi network: `10-09 16:03:41.341 13392 13392 W ssh     : type=1400 audit(0.0:10087): avc: granted { execute } for path=“/data/data/com.Termux/files/usr/bin/ssh” dev=“mmcblk0p80” ino=46315 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c1,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c1,c257,c512,c768 tclass=file app=com.termux`

This is the output of `ifconfig` on that network:

```
Warning: cannot open /proc/net/dev (Permission denied). Limited output.
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0
    unspec 00-...-00 txqueuelen 1000 (UNSPEC)

wlan0:  flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.83.23 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.83.255
    unspec 00-...-00 txqueuelen 3000 (UNSPEC)
```

And this is the output of `ifconfig` on my cellular data network:

```
Warning: cannot open /proc/net/dev (Permission denied). Limited output.
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00 txqueuelen 1000 (UNSPEC)

rmnet_data2: flags=65<UP,RUNNING> mtu 1500
        inet 10.45.55.16 netmask 255.255.255.224
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00 txqueuelen 1000 (UNSPEC)

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.13.194 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.13.255
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00 txqueuelen 3000 (UNSPEC)
```

Comment: It isn't ssh that is behaving differently.  There are routing and firewall issues involved here, but you haven't given enough details of the involved networks to answer without guessing.

Comment: I can definitely post the logcat outputs in just a second. So you have to configure your network to allow ssh - I wonder if there are limitations if you aren’t an admin of that network, i.e. just some public network somewhere.

Comment: Please let me know if there would be any more information I could provide that could clarify the situation better; thank you.

Comment: Clearly the two are on different networks, likely each with their own NAT gateway.  You're not going to have much luck connecting via the cellular network.  It might work to connect via your local office wifi, but if that doesn't work, you need to talk to a local network admin.

Comment: Thanks. Why do two machines have to be on the same network to use ssh?

Answer (score 1):

For two devices to talk to each other on a tcp/ip network, they either have to be on the same subnet or there needs to be a route between their respective subnets.  A firewall can be at any point between the devices and can selectively filter traffic.

Your two devices are in three separate networks:

- device 1: (wlan0)192.168.83.0/24
- device2: 10.45.55.0/27 (wlan0)192.168.13.0/24

All of these subnets are private subnets (see RFC 1918), and these addresses are not routable on the internet.  Organizations typically use these addresses ranges for internal networks.  If you have internet connectivity through addresses like this, then there is at least one NAT gateway between your device and internet that translates your address to another subnet and possibly aggregates your device's traffic with other devices onto the router's external address.  NAT gateways frequently also act as firewalls, blocking incoming connections to devices on their inside network.

If the networks in the private address spaces belong to the same organization, it is possible they are behind the same NAT and can talk to each other, although they could still have a firewall between them even if there is a route between them.

It is highly unlikely that your cellular data network can reach your ssh port on the wifi, but the two wlan0 networks at least have a chance.  You would have to talk to a network admin for your wifi networks to determine if or why there is a route between those subnets.

Comment: Thanks so much, that’s really elucidating. However, I once had a configuration in the past where I thought my Phone 1 was on cell data and giving out a WiFi hotspot (from the phone), and Phone 2 was on Phone 1’s hotspot and it successfully SSH’ed into Termux on Phone 1. Does that sound possible or was I mistaken? I.e. in theory why is a cellular data network more limited? Could it at least reach itself (as a WiFi hotspot) over SSH? Thanks very much

Comment: Secondly: I assume the important point would be of the network/firewall settings of the SSH server and not the device accessing that server remotely, wouldn’t it? As long as I have an SSH server on some network without a firewall, I could SSH into it from anywhere without limitation, is that correct?

Comment: In your first comment, there are two networks, and the cell network is not used, just the wifi connection between the phones.  In your second comment, remember there can be a firewall at every point -- each phone, and any router in between including a wifi router, although that does not mean there will be one.  Firewall can block both incoming and outgoing traffic, although they frequently don't.